# Image is not displayed in BarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I want to display the profile picture of the current user in my bar button item image. The default picture will be displayed but not the profile picture of the user.

Declaration of the bar button image:

```
lazy var leftButton: UIBarButtonItem = {
    var image = UIImage.init(named: "icons8-kontakte-50")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    let button  = UIBarButtonItem.init(image: image, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(ConversationViewController.showProfile))
    return button
}()
```

Here I observe the current user and get the current profile picture:

```
 //left bar button image fetching
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.leftButton
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.zero)

    UserApi.shared.observeCurrentUser { (currentUser) in
        self.currentUser = currentUser

        guard let url = URL(string: currentUser.profilImageUrl!) else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            if error == nil {
                let image = UIImage.init(data: data!)

                let contentSize = CGSize.init(width: 30, height: 30)
                UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(contentSize, false, 0.0)
                let _  = UIBezierPath.init(roundedRect: CGRect.init(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: contentSize), cornerRadius: 14).addClip()
                image!.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: contentSize))
                let path = UIBezierPath.init(roundedRect: CGRect.init(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: contentSize), cornerRadius: 14)
                path.lineWidth = 2
                UIColor.white.setStroke()
                path.stroke()
                let finalImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
                self.leftButton.image = finalImage

            }
        })
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A data task completion block can be called on any thread, but UI updates *must* be done on the main thread. You need to dispatch back to the main thread to update your `UIBarButtonItem`.

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
    guard error == nil, let data = data, let image = UIImage(data: data) else { return }
    let size = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
    let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
    let finalImage = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size).image { _ in
        let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect)
        path.addClip()
        image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size))
        path.lineWidth = 2.0
        UIColor.white.setStroke()
        path.stroke()
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.leftButton.image = finalImage.withRenderMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    }
}.resume()
```

You'll also need to call `resume()` on your data task.

Comment: One last question. How to display the datas like "aspectFill" in this case? The pictures are not displayed in their original size.